# Procrustes analysis with unequal number of points

Tags: algorithm, statistics, computational-geometry

As far as I understand Procrustes analysis takes into account the one-to-one ordering of the points across shapes. Therefore, you cannot run the algorithm if you have an unequal number of "anchor" or "landmark" points.

Is there another algorithm for shape alignment that works with unequal number of points across shapes? Say, minimizes the RMSE of the distance of points in one shape to the closest points in the other shape.

Thanks.

Comment: Having the same number of points is not enough. You need an explicit bijection, i.e. "correspondences".

Comment: Any solution yet? I have a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Procrustes analysis can be seen as final part of "point set registration" since you assume that you already know correspondences and what to align them using a rigid transformation:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_registration

However if your correspondences are unknown (or noisy) like in the case of two 3D scanned shapes, then you need to do a complete registration using for instance ICP (iterative closest points)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point

There are more sophisticated algorithms as well. Take into account that Point Set Registration is a special case of Shape Registration.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the problem is constrained, in the early stages of point set matching you have little clue on the pose.

Global strategies include

- choosing a few random correspondences, computing the corresponding transform and using it to find more correspondences; from there, estimate a goodness-of-fit score; repeat several times and keep the best score. [This is the RANSAC principle.]
- instead of choosing randomly, detect "feature points" that exhibit special properties, such as forming "corners" (in case of curve-like clouds), or dense concentrations...; then the number of correspondences to be tried is much lessened.